# How to count the number of visits to the site in a row?

Tags: php, algorithm

I need to give some bonus to users based on their retention day. For example:

```
2016-01-13 - [R0] day of my registration, I'll receive bonus x1
2016-01-15 - [R1] it's my first day of retention, the same for x2 bonus
2016-01-16 - [--] no visit
2016-01-17 - [R0] again bonus x1
2016-01-18 - [R1] again bonus x2
2016-01-19 - [R2] again bonus x3
2016-01-20 - [--] no bonus again
2016-01-21 - [R0] again bonus x1
```

I don't want to store users activity in sql table, I have redis storage and could store userId=>anyValue in it.

My thoughts was near this:

```
$registrationTimestamp = $User->getRegistration(); # we have the user registration date
$registrationMidnight = midnight($registrationTimestamp); # take 00:00 of this day
$todayMidnight = midnight(time()); # today 00:00

$dayOfRetention = ($todayMidnight - $registrationMidnight) / 86400;

if ($dayOfRetention === 0) {
    // user was registered today, do nothing
    return;
}

$currentDayOfRetention = $User->getDayOfRetention(); # get current value from redis
if ($dayOfRetention - $currentDayOfRetention === 1) {
    // user was on site yesterday
    // GAVE HIM BONUS x $dayOfRetention
}
$User->setDayOfRetention($dayOfRetention); # and increment it anyway
```

But I don't think what this is the best solution. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the difference of time between visits and hope you must be managing single time zone like the stackoverflow dooes??

Comment: what does you mean? I can't know the difference between visits, users can visit my site at anytime. server has a single timezone, do not understand the problem.

Comment: why do you think it is not a good solution? (which aspect of requirements is not satisfied with this code snippet?)